# Select the first row from two tables

Tags: mysql, union

I know MySQL doesn't have a TOP 1 function for selecting the the first row. So I use limit 1 to do it. But how can I select the first row from two tables (tableX, tableY) at the same time.

like this?

```
SELECT * FROM Database.tableX 
limit 1, Database.tableY limit 1
```

Comment: What defines the first rows in either table? What is the connection?

Comment: No connection between two table so I need to process those tables one row by one row.

Comment: @samuel so if there's no connection between the tables, then what you're asking makes no sense.  Also there's no such thing as the "first" row of a table unless you use ORDER BY to tell MySQL how you want the rows to be sorted.

Comment: OIC, that why I have problem(s) with my statement(s). I design my whole statements (actually program) on an assumption that the SQL can notice first and last row. And, no matter what function I use I always get a Cartesian product frist. lol good point @Gavin Towey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Database.TableX, Database.TableY
LIMIT 1
```

or maybe this?

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM Database.TableX LIMIT 1) t1,
  (SELECT * FROM Database.TableY LIMIT 1) t2
```

Comment: first solution works for the first row only, but it won't work if you need to process tables row by row, second solution could be used row by row. Otherwise, you need to use a UNION ALL query.

Comment: Very good solutions, I used your first solution then insert the data to a new table then use other two SQL statment to delete the old ones. then job done. again Thanks. Save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible unless there is some kind of relation between the two rows.
The other answers here try to join two rows, but they give no guarantee that it is the first row in each table. They also assume there is a field that can be matched from the two tables.

My best suggestion is to do two queries:

`SELECT * FROM Database.tableX limit 1;`

`SELECT * FROM Database.tableY limit 1;`

EDIT: you should also add a ORDER BY to tell MySQL how to sort the rows.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, if the table definitions match:

```
SELECT * FROM Database.tableX LIMIT 1 
UNION ALL
(
 SELECT * FROM Database.tableY LIMIT 1
)
```

Note the inner bracket is necessary. Else the optimizer will limit the result set to 1 seeing the last `LIMIT 1` clause